# What is wrong with this pattern: Pattern.compile("\\p{Upper}{4}")

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a `Pattern` matching a `String` consisting of 4 upper-case letters.

For instance:

- "AAAA"
- "ABCD"
- "ZZZZ"

... are all correct matches, while:

- "1DFG"
- "!@#$"
- "1234"

... should **not** be matched.

Find my code below.

It keeps returning `false` on "AAAA".

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

```
public static boolean checkSettings(String str) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Upper}{4}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("%str".format(str));
    if (m.matches()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        // System.exit(1)
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use [A-Z]{4}

Comment: @Mark That won't make any difference

Comment: This is highly suspicious: `"%str".format(str)` The `format` method is static, so the `%str` string is ignored. The first parameter, here `str`, is the format string, so if the string that is passed in contains any formatting symbols your method will crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's nothing wrong with your `Pattern`, probably something bad with your input `String`.

Take this example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Upper}{4}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("%str".format("AAAA"));
System.out.println(m.find());
```

Output:

```
true
```

**Warning**

`\\p{Upper}{4}` and `\\P{Upper}{4}` are **not** the same `Pattern`, but rather one the opposite of one another.

The second instance negates 4 upper-case characters (see the uppercase "P"). I'm pointing this out because your question title indicates the wrong `Pattern`.

**Final note**

If you only plan to use ASCII alphabetic characters for your `Pattern`, you might want to use `[A-Z]` (upper-case important here), as mentioned by others in this thread. It's the exact equivalent of `\\p{Upper}`.

There is a slight difference with `\\p{Lu}`, which would match the [Unicode category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) for upper-case letter.

Comment: Agree.  `\p{Upper}{4}` looks right to me, and actually works in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

change your pattern to:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{4}");
```

change your matcher to:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
```

Comment: hello zack, would you mind to explain why my expressions are not correct? thanks!

Comment: Well, I've no idea what `\\p{Upper}` is doing, but I would think that `"%str".format(str)` where str = "AAAA" would result in "AAAAtr" as %s is used to replace a string, so tr would be appended. Thus, any string you pass in would have lower case letters.

Comment: @ZackNewsham `"%str".format(str)` is highly suspicious, but it does not do what you said it does ("%str" is *not* a format string, so it gets ignored).

Comment: No, ```"%str"``` is an instance of String, and you call the class method ```format``` on a String, resulting in a new String (that has nothing to do with ```"%str"``` any more). Compare it to ```String.format("AAAA")```.

Comment: Yes, you're right - I don't think I've seen that notation before.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should give the correct result *if* you really pass in `AAAA`.
You should however rewrite your code like this:

```
public static boolean checkSettings(String str) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Upper}{4}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(String.format(str));
    return m.matches();
}
```

or even

```
public static boolean checkSettings(String str) {
    return str.matches("\\p{Upper}{4}");
}
```

These samples are widely equivalent to your code. I just tested it, it returns `true` for `AAAA`.